# Повторное внесение изменений из прошлых коммитов

Tags: git

Рисунок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим есть коммит (1) с файлом в котором есть строка. От него образован другой коммит (2) в другой ветке в котором эта строка удалена. Затем при слиянии синей ветки с красной получили коммит (3) где этой строки уже нет.

Вопрос:

Как можно влить в красную ветку старый коммит (1) со всей историей предков, что бы получит коммит (4) ? - эта операция отмечена зеленым цветом.

---

этот рисунок для примера, просто я давно вел ветку. шло время и в проекте появилось много всего нового. эта ветка влита в релизную версию, но из за изменений там скажем отсутствуют файлы из моей ветки. и я не хочу разбиратся что было изменено вручную просматривая все коммиты. мне нужно чтобы я взял коммит где все что нужно работает как мне надо и заново влить в релиз что бы увидеть конфликты и влить ранее сделанное.

Comment: посмотри про git rebase, возможно тебе это требуется

Answer (score 1):

## Если вы точно знаете, в каком коммите было «хорошо»

Если был какой-то коммит, в котором «всё работало» или были нужные файлы, то можно вытащить их содержимое. Для этого нужно знать указатель на коммит и путь к файлу.

### Восстановить целый файл

```
git checkout <хороший-коммит> -- path/filename.txt
```

### Восстановить часть строк в файле

```
# начинаем так же
git checkout <хороший-коммит> -- path/filename.txt

# поскольку изменения явно добавлены в файлы, индекс можно очистить
git reset path/filename.txt

# теперь выберем нужные изменения из файла в режиме patch
git add -p path/filename.txt

# Проверяем, что добавили только нужное
git diff --cached
# и делаем коммит
git commit
```

> Ограничение этого подхода в том, что вы фактически создаете новые файлы или строки от своего имени. То есть изначальное авторство строк теряется. Это помешает использовать `git blame`.

## Если вы точно знаете, в каком коммите стало «плохо»

Если нежелательные изменения были внесены в одном или нескольких коммитах, можно явным образом их отменить с помощью `git revert`.

### Отменить **все** изменения из коммита:

```
git revert <sha-коммита-2>
```

### Отменить **часть** изменений:

```
git revert <sha-коммита-2> --no-commit
# поскольку изменения явно добавлены в файлы, индекс можно очистить
git reset .

# теперь выберем нужные файлы
git add filename.txt

# если в файле было много изменений и вы хотите отменить только часть,
# можно добавить только нужные строки в режиме patch
git add -p filename

# все остальные изменения выкидываем
git checkout .

# когда всё готово, делаем из этого коммит.
git commit
```

### Как это работает

«Под капотом» у `git revert` происходит вот что:

1. В **файлы в рабочей области** добавляются изменения, отменяющие изменения указанного коммита. Все изменения от последующих коммитов сохраняются. Обратите внимание, что это совсем не то же самое, что вернуть файлы к состоянию в коммите перед «плохим».
2. Изменённые файлы добавляются в индекс git.
3. Запускается создание нового коммита. Откроется редактор, в котором вы напишете сообщение коммита.

При этом не будет такой структуры, как у вас на рисунке — но она и не нужна.

Comment: нет я не хочу отменять. этот рисунок для примера, просто я давно вел ветку. шло время и в проекте появилось много всего нового. эта ветка влита в релизную версию, но изза изменений там скажем отсутствуют файлы из моей ветки. и я не хочу разбиратся что было изменено вручную просматривая все коммиты. мне нужно чтобы я взял коммит где все что нужно работает как мне надо и заново влить в релиз что бы увидеть конфликты и влить ранее сделанное.

Comment: @perfect Это немного другая задача. Что же вы сразу так не написали?

Comment: Извеняюсь если ввел в заблуждение, дополните ответ пожалуста, а я дополню вопрос

Comment: @perfect кстати, а вас не беспокоит, что файлы были кем-то сознательно удалены, т.е. на это была причина? Если вы теперь их восстановите, вместе с ними не восстановятся ли какие-нибудь баги?

Comment: они были удалены по ошибке

Comment: обновил вопрос .

Comment: @perfect ну вот если они были просто удалены по ошибке, то сработает `git revert <коммит-где-файлы-были-удалены>`. Вообще, оба предложенных способа должны сработать.

Comment: решилось все с помощью rebase с последующим merge. при rebase можно было отменить удаление и правки файлов

Comment: У команды **git-checkout** есть параметр `-p`, который позволит избавиться от лишних **git-rest** и **git-add**.

Comment: @mymedia о, вот об этом я забыл